# Choose type in foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

in my program, I use 4 stored procedures, depending on fields that were selected in the form.

```
ctx = new DataClassesDataContext();
items = (from prjs in ctx.sp_Select_Stuknummers(prjnr) select prjs).ToList();
```

or

```
ctx = new DataClassesDataContext();
items = (from prjs in ctx.sp_Select_Stuknummers_Scanner(prjnr, scanner) select prjs).ToList();
```

and so on ...

I use LINQ to SQL, and for each of these 4 queries, I have a different result class:

```
sp_Select_StuknummersResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_ScannerResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_Scanner_WPSResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_StuknummerResult
```

they all have the same fields and definitions.

Now, when I iterate the result:

```
foreach (sp_Select_StuknummersResult x in items)
        {
            WPSitems ding = new WPSitems();
            ding.ID = x.ID;
            ding.Naam = x.Naam;
        ......

        }
```

I need to pass the type to use (in this example: sp_Select_StuknummersResult )

Is there a way to either 
A. easily convert to a new type, so that one can be used every time
or
B. dynamically set the type in the foreach loop ?

maybe there is even a C that I am not aware of...
Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but does `foreach (var x in items.OfType<sp_Select_StuknummersResult>())` do what you want? If not, can you try to explain it a different way?

Comment: I don't really see how this could help. In your remark I still need to put in <sp_Select_StuknummersResult> That's the part that I want to make dynamic.

Comment: Then you need to consider having a common base class or have each of the classes implement a common interface.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understand correctly but you can use a generic type and you can write the actual type once, when you call the method.
A better solution would be to define a common interface for those types, let them implement it and use that interface as a result of linq and the type of foreach. This way you can make simple casting as well if needed. 
Oh, @Enigmativity was faster suggesting the common interface. :)

Comment: @commenters: OP is using Linq 2 Sql. There is an out-of-the-box solution to his problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, L2S auto-generates a separate type for each individual stored procedure. However, you can easily change that return type in the Linq-2-Sql Designer.

In the designer, click on the stored procedure. In the Properties window, there's an entry 'Return Type': change it from 'Auto-generated type' to the type you want.

If the stored procedure returns rows from an already mapped table, select that type in the drop-down. If not, you can manually add a class to the designer and configure that type to be returned from the stored procedure.

[image: example]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Plain and simple. Thanks to all those who have contributed, but this one suited my needs best.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly this might help you out:

1.) Create an interface for the result classes (e.g.) `I_SP`:

```
sp_Select_StuknummersResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_ScannerResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_Scanner_WPSResult
sp_Select_Stuknummers_StuknummerResult
```

- add common variables and methods that you need into that interface.

2.) Make sure your `items` is `List<I_SP>`

3.) Create a generic method for your `foreach` loop

```
public void MyMethod<T>(List<I_SP> items) where T:I_SP {
  foreach (var x in items.OfType<T>)
  {
    WPSitems ding = new WPSitems();
    ding.ID = x.ID;
    ding.Naam = x.Naam;
    ......
  }
}
```

4.) Then just call this like this:

```
MyMethod<*sp_Select_StuknummersResult result class*>(items);
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: For this approach to work one will have to add partial classes (to make the different sp_Select_Stuknummers* classes implement the common interface.The OP is using Linq 2 SQL, which has a facility out of the box to unify the types of all stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using generics/reflection.

```
public static WPSitems MapObjectWithIdenticalProperties<T>(T itemOfUnknownType) where T : new() 
    {
        var inputType = typeof(T);

        var outputType = typeof(WPSitems);

            var outputItem = new WPSitems();
            foreach (var inputProperty in inputType.GetProperties())
            {
                var matchingOutputProperty = outputType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == inputProperty.Name);
                if(matchingOutputProperty != null)
                    matchingOutputProperty.SetValue(outputItem, inputProperty.GetValue(itemOfUnknownType));
            }
        return outputItem;
    }
```

The function above can be called like this:

```
var items = GetYourDataThatCanBeDifferentTypes();
var mappedItems = new List<WPSitems>();

foreach(var item in items)
    mappedItems.add(MapObjectWithIdenticalProperties(item));
```

Comment: Don't do this. Although it will work, it is really overkill, and may introduce a performance issue. At the very least, it introduces code that is unnecessarily difficult to read and understand.